# How to create a 403 Forbidden error template and render it

Tags: zend-framework2

I would like to create a 403 Forbidden error template and render it from a controller.

In my module.config.php I have the following entry.

```
    'view_manager' => array(
    'display_not_found_reason' => true,
    'display_exceptions'       => true,
    'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
    'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
    'forbidden_template'       => 'error/403',
    'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
    'template_map' => array(
        'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
        'application/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/application/index/index.phtml',
        'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
        'error/403'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/403.phtml',
        'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
    ),
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
),
```

As you can see I have added a 403 template and a 403.phtml to my view/error folder.

In my controller I have tried.

```
$response = $this->getResponse();
$response->setStatusCode(403);
```

But nothing happens, the default page is rendered.  When I change the 403 to a 404 in the above code the 404 error page is rendered.

Please can someone tell me what I am missing, many thanks.

Comment: you need to create listener that would inject it https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Mvc/View/Http/RouteNotFoundStrategy.php https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Mvc/View/Http/ExceptionStrategy.php

Answer (score 0):

Try to use onBootstrap to do this kind of things (if it fits in your app). Imagine you attach an event to listen on EVENT_ROUTE:

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $event) {
    $eventManager = $event->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE, array($this, 'protectPage'), -100);
}
```

Now in protectPage function, we may decide at any point to set response to forbidden(403):

```
public function protectPage(MvcEvent $event) {
   $match = $event->getRouteMatch();
   ...
   $response = $event->getResponse()->setStatusCode(403);
   //If the 403 template doesnt show, you may try to redirect to an action which has the template. check the following lines.
   $match->setParam('controller', 'User\Controller\Account');
   $match->setParam('action', 'denied');
   ...
}
```